# How to compile for Windows 8 using MinGW on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, mingw

I have a simple HelloWorld application

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n') {}
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with MinGW on Windows 7 with command

```
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe
```

In my computer it runs well, but when i move it to another computer with clean Windows 8, it doesn't start. After double clicking it, it shows "loading" cursor and it's loading and loading ... and never starts console and executes, no error message. The process is not listed anywhere in task manager and if i try to delete the exe file, it says it's being used by process System. Only restart makes it possible to delete this file.

What is wrong? How can i compile a program for Windows 8 and later on my Windows 7?

EDIT: i compiled the program with Visual C++ 2008 compiler and it does the same.

Comment: Maybe UAC is getting in the way?

Comment: why? it just prints a message, why would it need a admin privileges?

Comment: Its Microsoft.  They do a lot of crazy things.

Comment: Are you using `aVast`? If so disable it and try again. aVast is known to block c++ compiled code from several compilers.

Comment: Ye, it was Avast blocking it. On other computers with Windows 8 but other anti-virus, the program started. It seems to be some corrupted installation, because on yet another computer with Avast, it first scanned the executable and then it let it start normally.